# How do I use this specifc form of homography on an image?

Tags: opencv, homography

This [paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2008.03722.pdf) (Online Extrinsic Camera Calibration for Temporally Consistent IPM
Using Lane Boundary Observations with a Lane Width Prior) introduces a way to find extrinsic parameters for a camera and then use those alongside known intrinsic parameters to create a homography. The details on how to apply the obtained homography are vague and I don't fully understand the parameters `a_x` and `a_z` and certainly not the parameters `b_x` and `b_z` in the homography. Here is the method in question:

> [image]

So far I have tried to apply the homography using the opencv function [warpPerspective](https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/da/d54/group__imgproc__transform.html#gaf73673a7e8e18ec6963e3774e6a94b87) but to no avail.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.